# Use multiplied columns result in Where clause

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query where I multiply three columns as 'overall win'. Then I want to use a condition for overall_win to be >400. However the query only works without this condition. what can I do?

```
SELECT 
 *,(`obj_purchasePrice`*`win_per_100000_EUR_invest`*`rent_factor`/100000) AS `overall_win` 
FROM local_data.house_data 
WHERE geo_plz IN (10115,10117) AND `date`>='2019-10-29' AND `overall_win`>='400'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of column alias in where condition is not allowed  because the where clause is eavluated  before the select clause
so You should repeat the code

```
SELECT   *
  ,(`obj_purchasePrice`*`win_per_100000_EUR_invest`*`rent_factor`/100000) AS `overall_win` 
FROM local_data.house_data 
WHERE geo_plz IN (10115,10117)
  AND `date`>='2019-10-29' 
    AND (`obj_purchasePrice`*`win_per_100000_EUR_invest`*`rent_factor`/100000)>='400'
```

or you could use an HAVING clause (this clause work on select result and is applied  ad the end of the select just before the presentation of the result

```
SELECT   *
  ,(`obj_purchasePrice`*`win_per_100000_EUR_invest`*`rent_factor`/100000) AS `overall_win` 
FROM local_data.house_data 
WHERE geo_plz IN (10115,10117) AND `date`>='2019-10-29' 
HAVING  `overall_win`  >='400'
```

Answer (score 1):

that is nor allowed, you can repeat the calculation in the where Clause or do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
     *,(`obj_purchasePrice`*`win_per_100000_EUR_invest`*`rent_factor`/100000) AS `overall_win` 
    FROM local_data.house_data 
    WHERE geo_plz IN (10115,10117) AND `date`>='2019-10-29' ) t1
WHERE`overall_win`>='400'
```